# Best practice to avoid dichotomic class switching in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, duplicates, code-duplication

I wrote a method in a javascript class. The method colors a pressed div green if the same div contains the class *right* and red if it contains the class *wrong*. The function (or method) does that via another class called bg-* (+ the bootstrap nomenclature *success, danger* etc.) for its background color.

Here's the code:

```
this.clickedOnAnswer = function(clickedAnswer) {
    $('#' + clickedAnswer).not($('.wrong')).removeClass('bg-light text-dark').addClass('bg-success text-white');
    $('#' + clickedAnswer).not($('.right')).removeClass('bg-light text-dark').addClass('bg-danger text-white');
}
```

Although it does work, I hate duplicated code. How to do this in more elegant way?

Comment: Depends. We don't know the full range of possibilities. Can clickedAnswer have (a) both classes 'wrong' and 'right'?, (b) neither 'wrong' nor 'right'? Both seem unlikely but we don't know for sure unless we are told.

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.clickedOnAnswer = function(clickedAnswer) {
  $(clickedAnswer).removeClass('bg-light text-dark').addClass('text-white bg-' + ($(clickedAnswer).hasClass('wrong')? 'danger' : 'success'));
}
```

```css
button {padding:3px 7px}
.bg-light {background:#fec}
.text-dark {color:#333}
.bg-danger {background:red}
.bg-success {background:green}
.text-white {color:#fff}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="wrong bg-light text-dark" onclick="clickedOnAnswer(this)">Wrong</button>

<button class="right bg-light text-dark" onclick="clickedOnAnswer(this)">Right</button>
```